# iOS BLE problem didUpdateValueForCharacteristic not called ios14

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth, ios14

We have a peripheral device and I am trying to connect it with iOS device. It was working fine with Swift 3.0 But when I am trying to convert it in Swift 5.0 it did not work. It is working perfectly fine with Android device. So it is not an issue of hardware.

I have successfully connected and also discovered services and characteristics. My characteristics give me notify property only, I set that to true which also triggered the didupdateNotificationStateFor delegate method and it showed the characteristic.isnotifying as true. Which meant my subscription is successful. The only problem I am facing is didUpdateValueForCharacteristic is never been called. My code is as under.

```
extension HRMViewController: CBPeripheralDelegate {
  func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didDiscoverServices error: Error?) {
    guard let services = peripheral.services else { return }
    for service in services {
      print(service)
      peripheral.discoverCharacteristics(nil, for: service)
      // break
    }
  }
  
  
  func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didDiscoverCharacteristicsFor service: CBService, error: Error?) {
    guard let characteristics = service.characteristics else { return }
    for characteristic in characteristics {
      print(characteristic)
   
      if characteristic.properties.contains(.read) {
        print("\(characteristic.uuid): properties contains .read")
        peripheral.readValue(for: characteristic)
      }
   
      if transferCharacteristic.properties.contains(.notify) {
        print("\(characteristic.uuid): properties contains .notify")
         peripheral.setNotifyValue(true, for: characteristic)
        
      }
      
      if characteristic.properties.contains(.write){
      }
      
    }
  }
  
 
  func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didUpdateValueFor characteristic: CBCharacteristic, error: Error?) {
    
       
    switch characteristic.uuid {
    case aCBUUID:
     lblResult.text = "UUID: \(characteristic.uuid) Value = \(String(describing: characteristic.value))"
    case bCBUUID:
     
      lblResult2.text = "UUID: \(characteristic.uuid) Value = \(String(describing: characteristic.value))"
        case f:
      print("CORRECT Characteristic UUID: \(characteristic.uuid)")
      print(characteristic.value ?? "no value")
    
      
      
    default:
      print("Unhandled Characteristic UUID: \(characteristic.uuid)")
      print(characteristic.value ?? "no value")
    }
  }
  
  func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didUpdateNotificationStateFor characteristic: CBCharacteristic, error: Error?) {
    if error != nil {
      print("Error ==",error?.localizedDescription ?? "")
    }
    
    print("updateNotification: \(characteristic.isNotifying)")
      
  
  }
```

Any help in this regard is highly appreciated.

Comment: Do you save the connected peripheral in a strong property?

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  
Here is my declaration line.
'var myPeripheral : CBPeripheral!
myPeripheral = peripheral' 
I think its strong.

Comment: Yes, it is. Do you assign the value in `didConnect`?

Comment: we have done this in didDiscover as under
`func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didDiscover peripheral: CBPeripheral,
                      advertisementData: [String : Any], rssi RSSI: NSNumber) {
    print(peripheral.name as Any)
    if peripheral.name  == "BT-TH-300D8ED5"
    {
      myPeripheral = peripheral
      myPeripheral.delegate = self
      centralManager.stopScan()
      centralManager.connect(myPeripheral)
    }
  }`

Comment: Can you share your ```didConnect``` code?  I notice you placed the delegate in ```didDiscover``` instead of in ```didConnect```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I did not get any notification. Here is the code
` func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didConnect peripheral: CBPeripheral) {
    print("Connected!")
    myPeripheral.delegate = self
    myPeripheral.discoverServices([heartRateServiceCBUUID])
    } `
Previously I was setting the delegate in the `didDiscover` but as per your suggestion I have set the delegate in `didConnect` but same result.